# Rewrite index.php and index.html in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Using `.htaccess`, how can I rewrite the URL, such that when a visitor types:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php
http://www.domain.com/index.html
```

they will be redirected to `http://www.domain.com/`.

I tried it with redirection, but it takes me in the loop...

Please if you could help me with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html?)$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What would the difference be if the flags were [NC,R,L] instead of [R=301,L]?

Comment: @JosiahSprague it would also match InDeX.pHp because of NC, and redirect with status code 302 instead of the desired 301.